How can I use Edge TPU on yolov8?
Hello im currently running a yolov8 code for object detection and tracking. The problem is that the fps is super slow like about 0.5 to 1 fps only. I'm eyeing to buy an Edge TPU to increase fps speed of my project. Will Edge TPU work on yolo models(pt)? Note that the code I made has gpio outputs when it detects vehicles. I just want to improve its real time detection fps. Hope you can help me guys.
I've tried searching but only found converting yolo models to TensorFlow lite to use Edge TPU.

What is your current device? Your search result is relevant, you need to convert the yolov8.pt model to .tflite format to run it on Edge TPU. Here is an official instruction: https://docs.ultralytics.com/integrations/edge-tpu/?h=export. Also, look at this discussion: https://github.com/ultralytics/ultralytics/issues/8673#issuecomment-1979244065.

thank you will try to do sorry for the late respond
